# Error while creating table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

currently using SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production
Any help would be appreciated.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Distributed_Movie_List (
Distribution_ID Number(8) PRIMARY KEY,
Movie_ID Number(5) REFERENCES Movies(Movie_ID),
Distributor_ID Number(3) REFERENCES Movie_Distributors(Distributor_ID), 
Distribute_Type varchar2(10),
Inventory_Quantity Number(3), 
Unit_Price Number(8,2)
);

CREATE TABLE Distributed_Movie_List (Distribution_ID Number(8) PRIMARY KEY, 
Movie_ID Number(5) REFERENCES Movies(Movie_ID),
Distributor_ID Number(3) REFERENCES Movie_Distributors(Distributor_ID), 
Distribute_Type varchar2(10),
Inventory_Quantity Number(3), 
Unit_Price Number(8,2))
                                                                                                                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: Either the table `movies` or `Movie_Distributors` does not exist

Comment: Have you checked that your referenced FK tables, `Movies` and `Movie_Distributors` exist? In the correct Schema?

Comment: Thank you that seemed to be the case, let me go through my code again!

Comment: @Scorpion: If you enter the command as 1 complete line, debugging is complexed by the fact "all errors occur in line 1". If you have different lines, he would state a line containing the REFERENCES word, as that is where we seem to think there is a problem. If you create a table, the table obviously doesn't exist. But, you're referring to other tables, so ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the line `Distributor_ID Number(3) REFERENCES Movie_Distributors(Distributor_ID)`.

According to the position of the asterisk in the error message, `Movie_Distributors` does not exist (or the user issues the `create table` statement may not have permissions to it).

Comment: Thank you that seemed to be the case, the table it was trying to refer to was created AFTER the initial table, I changed order and it worked.